# How can I set a panel as active in Bootstrap 5 accordion on page load?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap newbie here, I have my accordion setup with my last item set to `class="accordion-collapse collapse show"`

The item opens when the page is loaded however the first panel is selected by default. How can I change this?

Example:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Accordion Item #1
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Accordion Item #2
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Accordion Item #3
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have only `.accordion-button` on the open item's button and `.accordion-button.collapsed` on the closed items' buttons.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```